# Selenium with Ruby - cannot access HTML elements that I want

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

I am following SauceLab's Ruby and Selenium guidebook - it's a free book to help teach Selenium in combination with Rspec. In the first real example of the book, the author leads us to write a test script that goes to this link:
http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login

Our script then will insert the appropriate uname and pwd (listed in text on the page... it's tomsmith and SuperSecretPassword!), and then submit the form.

All of the above works - then it goes a little further and looks to introduce an assert to ensure that we got to the correct page (the page that results from successful login). This assert, even when I do as per the example in the book, does not work. It can't find the element, and says so as here:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(@driver.find_element(css: '.flash.success').displayed?)

 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError:
   Unable to locate element: .flash.success
 # ./ruby_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I was hoping I could get some help from SO in helping me formulate a working assert to ensure I'm on the login page after successful login via test script. Here is my code so far

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

describe 'Login' do


before(:each) do
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
end

after(:each) do
 @driver.quit
end

it 'test_to_succeed' do
 @driver.get 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login'
 @driver.find_element(id: 'username').send_keys('tomsmith')
 @driver.find_element(id: 'password').send_keys('SuperSecretPassword!')
 @driver.find_element(id: 'login').submit
 expect(@driver.find_element(css: '.flash.success').displayed?) #line that fails every run
end
end
```

Minus a little revised rspec syntax, this is exactly as what is listed in the book. The book has for the failing line as below, with some deprecated syntax:

```
@driver.find_element(css: '.flash.success').displayed?.should be_true
```

But this also fails with the exact same error above. To further suss out it being my expect(), I have tested the expect() syntax for other elements to test that it is working/not the source of the problem. The source of the problem, instead, is that my script is not resolving the css element as the book indicates it would be able to. It can't find '.flash.success', in loose terms.

So I went to page source of the successful login page and found some other things I could assert against. This came as attractive since it is unique to the success page:

```
<div data-alert id='flash' class='flash success'>
        You logged into a secure area!
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
      </div>
```

But alas, I found the exact same failures when trying this in my code:

```
 expect(@driver.find_element(class: 'flash success').displayed?) #line that fails every run
```

or even

```
 expect(@driver.find_element(id: 'flash').displayed?) #line that fails every run
```

Essentially, I'm a little mystified how I am supposed to get a unique element off of the successful login page to assert correctly. All the efforts above (including the one in the sample text that I'm learning from) would seem reasonable to work, to me... but it is not so. Rather than simply switching texts to one with working examples, I thought it would be more instructive for me to work out and try to discover why the examples above do not work.

Comment: What does `@driver.find_element(id: 'flash')` return? What if you (temporarily, for now, in lieu of a better solution) `sleep(5)` first? Is that `expect(...)` the full code?! You need to write something like `expect(....).to be_true` -- so what did you actually write, and what is the error message?

Comment: Hey Tom. You were going the right direction. I introduced a sleep before my assert and ta-dah it started working. Got lieu of the idea it would work on account that I printed to terminal the page_content and saw it was the old page_content it was displaying, in previous iterations of the code )-=. Was sad.

That expect as I've written it is correct - in most recent RSpec, expect can be put around any old boolean expression i.e. expect(true or false expression). It may not be idiomatic to use expect this way, however - that I'm not as sure.

Comment: Yep, welcome to **the biggest issue** with *all* selenium/related tools. This is *the* problem that QA testers have to face 100 times a day. There is no "silver bullet" solution -- lazy (bad) way is to cheat and use a `sleep()`. Better is to poll for the existence of something. Best of all is for your assertion to be *triggered* by something being loaded. Have a play, and see what you can make work.

Comment: Normally, Selenium should wait for the page to load before proceeding with the next step... I'm not sure why that's not working here; possibly because the form submit is happening as an `xhr`?